# What can I do to stop CollectionView refreshing the cell which was displayed when scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using UICollectionView to display images.

Here is my code:

```
- (WaterFallCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WaterFallCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:collectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSURL *itemTBURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.items[indexPath.item][@"image"][@"thumbnailLink"]];
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    cell.imageView.imageURL = itemTBURL;

    return cell;
}
```

My problem is, for example, it has totally 10 images in collectionView, first I scroll down to last one, which the first image in collectionView will be invisible, when I scroll up to the first one, it has the refreshing effect and the program will jump into the method I showed. It looks like when the cell turns from invisible to visible state, iOS will force to call the method. I want to store the previously displayed cell, so when you scroll up, it won't have the refresh effect. What should I do? I know Twitter, Pinterest, Facebook they looks like wont' refresh the previous cells when you scroll up. I know it is feasible, just don't know how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to cache the images that you are downloading and store them locally, not just in memory. The 'refreshing' effect you see is because the cells are dequeued as part of the reuse mechanism to ensure smooth scrolling.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the comments. Could you pls be more specific? Do I need to store the cell object along with the image locally? And when scrolling, check if the local has the cell object for that indexPath? If so, use it, if not dequeue another one?

Comment: You don't need to store the cell object, you just need to cache the image (store to the device in your sandbox for example). Then next time you come around you check to see if the image is in your cache, if it is, use it, if it isn't, download it. You might find https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage useful.

Comment: Agreed with Jeff. You can use SDWebImage along with the UIImageView category to load the images asynchronously. If the images are already downloaded, it'll skip the network operation and will just load them through the cache.

Answer (score 0):

What is "refresh effect"? What do you mean?

Everytime you scroll to new UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionView call cellForItemAtIndexPath: to get this cell.
Every cell is reusable. So, you can initialize cell for further reuse it in "- (void) prepareForReuse()" method of cell.

As far as I understand, every time you set imageView.imageURL - image start loading and after that, you show it, right? I think, you should cache this images after first loading.

In any case, there is no way to skip calling cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: because I am using dequeueResusableCellWithIdentifier method, which means, iOS will give a cell that is used before. So when I scroll up, I use the previously used cell and set the image. It looks like you reset an image on a cell which has a image previously. So that is the refresh effect I mean.

Comment: You should implement this method in your cell to prevent refreshing:
- (void) prepareForReuse
{
 self.imageView.image = nil;
}